# Calling more than 1 stored procedure in php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_update_NotifyTrainerStatus_in_notification_table`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_update_NotifyTrainerStatus_in_notification_table`(IN email VARCHAR(50), IN id BIGINT)
BEGIN

 SELECT @employee_id := `Employee_Id` FROM `employee_profile` WHERE `Email_Id` = email;

 UPDATE notification_status_table SET NotifyTrainerStatus=1 WHERE Employee_Id    =@employee_id AND Training_Id = id;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

this is my mysql query and i have to run this when a id=6 . i have my php code like below

```
if ( $id == 6 ) {
    // echo $trainingid;
    // echo "Inside id=6";
    mysql_query("call update_notify_trainer_in_status_table(" . $trainingid  . ")");
    $n = count( $to );
    // echo "count : ".$n;
    // foreach( $to as $values ) {
    for( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++ ) {
        // echo $values;
        $trainer_mail = $to[$i];
        echo $trainer_mail;
        //echo $trainingid;
        mysql_query("call  sp_update_NotifyTrainerStatus_in_notification_table('".$trainer_mail."' , " . $trainingid . ")")  or die( mysql_error() );
    }
}
```

My problem is this query runs fine for first  $trainer_mail and it doesn't run for second $trainer_mail. any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: call the procedure `foreach` value in the array.

Comment: `mysql_*()` API are deprecated. Use either the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension instead. [Deprecated mysql_*()](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: @ram Was your question answered?

Comment: yes Manatax my problem has been solved...

Comment: You might do well with making sure your question have an accepted answer. If you found the answer on your own, then share it with everyone and mark it as accepted. If you found the answer in a response by someone else, then mark it so. This will help others in the future pinpoint a solution to a problem similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean the connection after each call to a store procedure.
Try with this:

```
function mysqli_clean_connection($dbc) {
    while(mysqli_more_results($dbc)) {
        if (mysqli_next_result($dbc)) {
            $result = mysqli_use_result($dbc);
            if ($result!=NULL) {
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use mysqli, but you can adapt it